# Links not clickable in Chrome on Desktop View

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to discover why some links aren't clickable in chrome only and on desktop view. The links are clickable in safari and firefox, so not sure what's causing this. Also on mobile view, the links work although I cannot see any relevant changes to cause this.

The site is https://www.bhrhospitals.nhs.uk/ and I'm referring to the 'latest news' section. Both `.blog-post-title` and `.full-story-link` should be clickable.

Also I rarely create posts that link to code on external websites, so when doing this is it ok to post just the link and relevant HTML? The code can be found by just inspecting the site.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: When on chrome left click -> inspect element. Do you see any overlaping elements that are on top of your links?

Comment: The issue is related to `JS`, click event blocks it.

Comment: Try this :  pointer-events: auto;

Comment: @AnishSharma, it won't work. It is blocked by "bx slider" used for the carousel.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the class name of your slider container, I assume that you're using the bxSlider. You need to disable the `touchEnabled` option.

```
$('.blog-posts-list').bxSlider({
  touchEnabled: false
});
```

Comment: good suggestion, but pasting this into the JS console doesn't seem to work

Comment: Because it has already been initiated on DOM load. You need to make the change in the script itself